# Trackpad delay on 15" MacBook Pro with touchbar late 2016

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

I recently purchased the new 15" MacBook Pro with touchbar (late 2016). My trackpad is set to 'click' with either a press (audible click noise) or a tap. If I right click by using a two-finger press, the response on the screen is virtually instantaneous. However, if a use a two-finger tap, then there is a noticeable delay (generally under one second). When I first noticed the delay, this delay was about one second long with a spinning pin wheel sometimes popping up. I restarted the laptop, and the delay was significantly shorter, though still noticeable (maybe 0.25-0.5 seconds).

I'm trying to determine if it is a software or hardware issue before complaining to Apple. Is there a quick fix for this, or will I have to take the laptop to get repaired?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's a built-in delay allowing macOS to detect the smart-zoom gesture (two finger double-tap).  If you go to Settings → Trackpad and disable the smart zoom, does the delay go away or noticeably shorten?

Comment: Just to chime in that I had a similar (and exceedingly frustrating!) delay with two finger scrolling. A slight delay when trying to scroll a page with two fingers. Turning off "smart zoom" solved it for me to.